# Phone Contacts With Firebase User

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, contacts

I am creating a Chat App with Firebase, I can fetch users from firebase database. What I want is that my user list must only show users whose contacts are saved in my phone, instead of showing all the contacts. 
Iam not able to figure out how should i start. 
below is the fetch user method

```
func fetchUser(){
    Database.database().reference().child("Users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictonary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let user = Users()
            user.id = snapshot.key
         user.setValuesForKeys(dictonary)
            print(user.phoneNumber!,user.userName!,user.UserId!)


            self.users.append(user)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }


    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

And below is the function get to  contacts from phone

```
private func fetchContacts() {
    print("Attempting to fetch contacts today..")

    let store = CNContactStore()

    store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (granted, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Failed to request access:", err)
            return
        }
        if granted {
            print("Access granted")

            let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
            let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])

            do {

                try store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stopPointerIfYouWantToStopEnumerating) in


                    let ph = (contact.phoneNumbers[0].value ).value(forKey: "digits") as! String
                    self.contacts.append(Contact(givenName: contact.givenName, familyName: contact.familyName, phoneNumbers: ph))

                })

            } catch let err {
                print("Failed to enumerate contacts:", err)
            }

        } else {
            print("Access denied..")
        }
    }
}
```

Now what shall I do so that my tableview will only show users whose contacts are saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little bit tweak in the above code and i finally managed to make it possible

```
            func fetchUser(){
        Database.database().reference().child("Users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictonary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                let user = Users()
                user.id = snapshot.key
             user.setValuesForKeys(dictonary)
                ///////
                let store = CNContactStore()

                store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (granted, err) in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Failed to request access:", err)
                        return
                    }
                    if granted {
                        print("Access granted")

                        let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
                        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])

                        do {

                            try store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stopPointerIfYouWantToStopEnumerating) in


                                let ph = (contact.phoneNumbers[0].value ).value(forKey: "digits") as! String
                                self.contacts.append(Contact(givenName: contact.givenName, familyName: contact.familyName, phoneNumbers: ph))


                                if user.phoneNumber == ph {
                                    print("Similar Contact Found")
                                    self.users.append(user)
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                                    }
                                } else {

                                    print("Contacts Not Compared")

                                }

                            })

                        } catch let err {
                            print("Failed to enumerate contacts:", err)
                        }

                    } else {
                        print("Access denied..")
                    }
                }



            }


        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```